# CAEAGLLayer - OpenGL API's have no effect after Siri input

Tags: ios9, beta, caeagllayer

I'm seeing some pretty funny behavior on iOS 9 beta 5.  When Siri is used to speak a string into a UITextView, all my OpenGL calls targeted at my CAEAGLLayer no longer work.  There is nothing unusual with the rendering code, it just seems that they no longer have an effect once voice dictation has been used.

Has anyone else experienced this in the iOS 9 beta releases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this issue, I opened a radar with Apple and they have since owned it as a bug in iOS 9.  The bug was due to Siri knocking out the current EAGLContext.  The workaround as of now is to force your EAGLContext to be the current one every time you `presentRenderBuffer`.

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:myContext]
```